# Python 3: How to alternate between two players?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5

I have a code, that have five question and answer. if I run the code, I want it to ask the first player to choose between the four answer. if the player get it right or wrong, it should move on to the second player, and if the second get it right to wrong, the next question should be for the first player and so on till they are finish answering all the five question. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to alternate between two players using `if, else statement` until a specific `(answering all the question)` condition has been met?

Comment: this question is very brad, can you be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a code, that have five question and answer. if I run the code, I want it to ask the first player to choose between the four answer. if the player get it right or wrong, it should move on to the second player, and if the second get it right to wrong, the next question should be for the first player and so on till they are finish answering all the five question

Answer (score 0):

A good way to `alternate (switch)` between two player using an **`if, else statement`** will be to use for loop with an `if, else statement` inside the loop:

```
for question in range(6):
    if question % 2 == 0:
       player = "first"
    else:
      player = "second"
```